# Windows Vista Basic - I cannot copy file from CD

Tags: windows-vista

I have windows vista basic laptop.
There were two antivirus programs Symantec Norton Antivirus and Avast.
Both were removed. So there is no AV software at all.
I am trying to copy file (probably containing virus) but windows vista do not allows me to copy it from CD to my desktop... but it behaves like i would like either erase file from cd or copy to CD

It displays message: "Copying ...blblblba .." 
File on that CD is read only. You can copy on that rewritable CD new files, which replace files on that disc.  (it is Polish version so translation may be incorrect).
two buttons available RETRY and CANCEL

When I am trying to do the same but file is copied from pendrive to desktop it erases it from pendrive !!!! ahhhhhh

I tried to switch all security related services but still have same problem.
Does anyone have idea what is happening there?

Comment: Can you please make some screenshots to supplement the questions, I am not sure about what exactly is happening.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. 
Since Symantec NAV has couple components one of them was not uninstalled.
After uninstallation file could be copied without problems.

Comment: Please select this answer as correct. This way the question won't be bumped to the top from time to time as unanswered.